# ProfilePictureView to Bitmap (Facebook SDK for Android v3 )

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How can I convert from ProfilePictureView to Bitmap? It's possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got it!!

```
ImageView fbImage = ( ( ImageView)profilePictureFB.getChildAt( 0));
Bitmap    bitmap  = ( ( BitmapDrawable) fbImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just enable the DrawingCache of the ProfilePictureView and then call a getDrawingCache...  like this

```
 ProfilePictureView mImage = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
 mImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 mImage.setProfileId(user.getId());
```

and then when the profile picture is loaded...

```
 Bitmap bitmap = mImage.getDrawingCache();
```